# The nonexistence of absolute uncountability.

Tags: set-theory

Are there any examples of a set which is uncountable in a given axiomatization, which is denumerable in another?

Comment: Of course, let $X$ be defined by "$\omega_1$ if CH is true and $\omega$ if CH is false". Depending on your axioms this might define a countable or an uncountable set. Not sure if this is what you are looking for... your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: But maybe you are interested in [absoluteness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absoluteness#In_set_theory). The property of being uncountable is not absolute for models of ZFC.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one natural example, $\Bbb R^L$ is the set of all constructible reals. Assuming $V=L$, this is the set of all real numbers and therefore uncountable. On the other hand, assuming $\sf PFA$ the set is very much countable.

Comment: +1, but PFA's a bit overkill . . .

Comment: Sure, but it's also a rather natural axiom. Compared to sharps, which are technically natural... But technically natural.

Comment: That's fair - I find it less natural than sharps. The [inner model hypothesis](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.109.7482&rep=rep1&type=pdf) is another fun one. (I'm sure you're aware of it, I'm listing it for the OP's sake.)

Comment: Well, there is also "every uncountable set of reals has a perfect subset", which is also somewhat natural and implies that $\omega_1$ is a limit cardinal in $L$... :)